# facebook graph api - see name of users who shared my post

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, share

I am an admin of a page in FB.

I would like to see in graph-api who shared my post on the page like this:

```
{post_id}/sharedposts?limit=1000
```

1. I only see a list of 3 people while 100 shared the post. I am not sure why I can see only some of the posts.
2. Which access token do I need to use? I am currently using the access token that FB generates when I select my page from the dropdown

Comment: You only get to see posts that are readable to your app. For normal user posts, that means only if your app would happen to have user_posts permission from that particular user you would get the post, even if it is public.

Comment: Hi! It's a page, not an app. What does it mean granting access to my app?

Comment: Using the API requires an app. And granting access means logging in to your app and granting it the necessary permission.

Comment: Thanks. so how do I see only a few results? these people never gave access to my app.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.8/object/sharedposts says you need to use a user token with `user_posts` permission from a user that can see those posts. Whether that user is friends with the user that made the post is taken into account at this point.

Comment: Right, one user is friend with the page admin that posted it. but another friends also shared this post, and I don't see his share. any reason?
and the other 2 figures that shared it - one is not her friend and the other one is page

Comment: may i ask what the use case for this is? what for do you need the names?

Comment: Sure. I am doing FB live, and I would like that anytime a user shares the post - it would appear at the top with his name to encourage ppl to share the live event. I can do it easily with streaming HTML ontop of the live streaming and writing some js code to connect to graph api

Comment: You are not allowed to incentives people to share

Comment: @WizKid source?

Comment: Facebook Platform Policy which I assume you read

Comment: There is nothing wrong with encouraging to share. The idea of facebook policy that people will not share for no reason. in my case I would like people to share so more people will be awared of the live event, and watch it